# Automatically changing Python directory after running python script from excel using VBA

Tags: python, vba, shell

Thanks for looking at my problem.
I have a python script which is writing a new csv file in my current directory. I have make it python.exe using pyinstaller. What I am doing is, running this exe file using VBA form excel on a button click. Problem is after running exe using VBA my csv is saving in default documents folder instead of folder where my python.exe is. But If I run the python.exe directly without VBA then it's saving csv in my current directory. So how can I save csv in current directory after running python.exe using VBA

Here is my python code which creating new csv file:

```
csvfile = open("Mycsv" + '.csv', 'w')
cr = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
```

I have also tried using: `csvfile = open(os.getcwd() + "\Mycsv" + '.csv', 'w')` But didn't worked.

Here is my VBA code:

```
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    wsh.Run Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.path & "\python.exe" & Chr(34), windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Comment: I suspect you need to pass the working directory path from VBA to the `python.exe` as an argument. The python program has no way to know otherwise which directory your excel file was. It is an independent process.

Comment: you can try to change the working directory of WScript with  `wsh.CurrentDirectory = ...` before the `wsh.Run ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before saving the file you can use `os.chdir(some_path_to_directory)` to set the current working directory, and then save in this directory.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. None other than @Vincent's Answer worked perfectly. So I have used  `wsh.CurrentDirectory = Thisworkbook.path`  before `wsh.Run...` Thanks a lot...!

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the path for your csv file:

```
import os.path
save_path = 'C:/example/'
csvName = os.path.join(save_path, "Mycsv"+".csv") 
csvfile = open(csvName, "w")
```